# Understanding quasi normal modes of black holes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, perturbation-theory, normal-modes

I think I am missing some basic understanding of QNMs of black holes: for example, for the Kerr black hole Leaver has calculated the first few QNMs and has found that they are complex conjugated. I do not understand this: if the black has QNMs with negative imaginary parts, then, if the supposed time behavior is of the type $\exp(i\omega t)$, these modes explode exponentially, but we still say that the Kerr BH is stable.

Why? Do we simply neglect the negative imaginary part? In this way all the works devoted to the study of the stability of BHs become useless. I understand that this is not the case, but it conflicts with the existence of the negative imaginary part of the QNMs.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modes that  grow with time correspond to the black hole absorbing radiation incoming from infinity. These modes  have to exist because of time reversal symmetry: if there is a solution with radiation propagating out to infinity, then the  time-reversed solution  with radiation coming in from infinity must also exist. The same issue occurs for an antenna emiting  radiation -- it can also receive radiation. Which situation applies dictates the choice of what  boundary conditions are imposed.

Comment: So the works that study stability of BHs by calculating QNMs: how should I interprete their results? Simply that a particular system has a particular system of QNMs and compare with other systems QNMs?

Comment: I don't see that QNM's have much to do with stability. They are relevent in formation of black holes as they describe  the ringdown by  gravitational wave emission.

Comment: @mikestone Mode stability of is proven by showing that there no QNMs (satisfying outgoing boundary conditions) with negative imaginary part.

Comment: @mmeent. Interesting. I   thought the arguments of Hawking and Ellis and the no-hair theorem would preclude an instability.   Is there a good reference?

Comment: The classic reference for this is Whiting’s 1988 paper: https://inspirehep.net/literature/267337